# Sonarqube Server is stopped unexpected while starting sonarqube in windows

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to start sonarqube in my windows machine with the help of StartSonar.bat file but I'm getting the issue below.

Please help me solve this.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:33 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\karthikr\Downloads\sonarqube-6.7.5\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp\sq-process8845422811086275444properties
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.01.22 16:11:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Have a look in the other log files. Does the user that starts the batch file have read/write access rights for the SonarQube folder?

Comment: It is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54264974/4944847. The only difference is you have SonarQube 6.7.5 instead of SonarQube 7.5.